How to fix t.AddLayer is not a function
I have this code
   var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 5);
var    marker = new L.Marker([100,20], {draggable:false});

 L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Shaded_Relief/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
    attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri',
    maxZoom: 13
}).addTo("map")
function onMapClick(e) {
    marker.setLatLng(e.latlng);
    document.getElementById('lat').value = e.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById('long').value = e.latLng.lng();
  };
marker.addTo('map')
map.on('click', onMapClick);


And it keeps on give T.addLayer is not defined so the map doesn't load, could you help me. Thank you

Replace addTo("map") with addTo(map).
